# PHP-SMTP header and user parameters

Tags: php, email, header, smtp

When sending mail via smtp, should the "from" value put into the email header
be the same as the username you connect to the host server with?

Because that user mail account on the host server is being used to the send mails. So I think it is the right value to put into the header value "from." Just wanted confirmation.

In this case I assigned it(mysmtp@mydomain.com) to $mysmtpmail which gets assigned to $username and $from

```
// Setup mail + session parameters
$host = $mysmtphost;
$username = $mysmtpmail;
$password = $mysmtppass;
$from = $mysmtpmail;
$to = $myemail;
$subject = "Form Mail";
$body = $_POST['name'] . "\n <br />" . $_POST['email'] . "\n <br />" . $_POST['msg'];

// Assign header parameters
$headers = array ('From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
     'Subject' => $subject,
    'Date'      => date('r', time()),);

// Assign Session Parameters
$mail = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
'port' => $port,
'auth' => true,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password));

$mail->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

Comment: +1 for clarifying ur doubts these small things matters a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Ideally yes, the from field should be same as username unless the user has selected an alternative mail id from which the mail has to be sent.

Clients like `outlook/thunderbird` gives you an option to select the mail id using which the mail need to be sent.(these ids are the already configured mail ids in outlook, only if more than 1 ids are configured)

Also mailers like rediffmail, outlook.com, etc. gives u a flexibility to configure multiple email-ids(usually by setting up `Pull mails`) and while sending the mail you can select any of the email ids as mail from. Ideally this id has to be in "from" field.

So beware if you are sending the mails for any reputed mailers which support these kind of functionalities.